# Is it possible to write unit tests with playwright/test, not using unit testing libs like jest/vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, svelte, e2e-testing, playwright, sveltekit

I've been trying to use playwright/test - playwright/experimental-ct-svelte libs.

If I've read the documentation; I can do unit testing as well without using jest. But I could not understand how I could mock my functions.

Also E2E test is just a part of our testing strategy; there has to be unit test coverage as well.

We expected we could cover all our test needings with playwright/test or experimental-ct-svelte; unit, component and e2e; but feel stuck at the moment.

What would you recommend us?

- We also need to support gherkin for BDD; so we think cucumber-js or jest-cucumber will be a good option for us to organise our step functions.

Answer (score 2):

Playwright has a ways to go before it can be considered a reliable unit test runner. It's definitely intended for e2e tests.

That being said, they came out recently with [experimental component testing functionality](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components) that might meet your needs (hard to tell without more details).

There's also a [pretty good walk-through from this guy](https://pkerschbaum.com/blog/using-playwright-to-run-unit-tests) that uses [Sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) with Playwright to achieve a decent unit testing setup.

Comment: thanks for the recommendations, Matt!